# Where should my windows app store cache and tempfiles?

Tags: windows, caching, temporary-files

Where should a windows application store cache data and temporary file data ?

I understand that

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + @"\" + "Cache";
```

is not a good idea since the program is going to probably be installed in

> Program Files\MyProgram\

for all users and users may not have access to writing to that folder.