# Where should I store application caches on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, caching

I have a Windows application that downloads various files. I would like to cache this files but I am unsure where to put the cache. It should live in the user's home folder, so that they always have access, but I don't think that folders such as `Documents` are appropriate.

The equivalent of what I am looking for on macOS and Linux are:

- `~/Library/Caches/MyApp`
- `~/.cache/MyApp`

Where should application caches be stored on Windows?

---

Note that unlike in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420234/where-should-my-windows-app-store-cache-and-tempfiles), I am not asking about temp files. My cache should be re-used across sessions.

---

Note that I am not building a Windows Store app.

Comment: There is no specific location tagged for storing cached data, AppData is for application specific data for the current user (CSIDL_APPDATA) I would use that.

Comment: That sucks. There being no specific folder for that means a user can't just delete caches for applications to free up space :/ And deleting all of AppData\Local would probably break a lot of stuff

Comment: What sucks even more is that apps usually don't clean up after themselves even after being uninstalled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per-user data that does not need to roam should be stored under [`CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494(v=vs.85).aspx). You can get this path by calling [`SHGetFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181(v=vs.85).aspx) (or [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx) in .NET). Use `CSIDL_APPDATA` instead if you need the data to roam in domain environments but it is not a good idea for large files...

Answer (score 3):

My final solution:

```
public static Path getCacheFolder(final String osName, final FileSystem fs) {

    Objects.requireNotNull(osName, "osName is null");
    Objects.requireNotNull(fs, "fs is null");

    // macOS
    if (osName.toLowerCase().contains("mac")) {
        return fs.getPath(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Library", "Caches");
    }

    // Linux
    if (osName.contains("nix") || osName.contains("nux") || osName.contains("aix")) {
        return fs.getPath(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".cache");
    }

    // Windows
    if (osName.contains("indows")) {
        return fs.getPath(System.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA"), "Caches");
    }

    // A reasonable fallback
    return fs.getPath(System.getProperty("user.home"), "caches");
}
```